# ajax call detect lack of response

Tags: javascript, ajax

I was wondering if there is a NON jquery solution to this scenario:

there is no reply to the ajax request because either the server got its internet connection down, the client got its internet connection down, or the server crashed. Is there some built in method/event in the xmlhttprequest object which can help in this issue ?

Comment: *"Is there some built in method/event in the xmlhttprequest object which can help in this issue?"* - There is.

Comment: care to be more enlighting? i can't seem to find something other than .open and .send

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the timeout property:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
            done(request.responseText);
        }
    },
    done = function (response) { console.log(response) },
    fail = function () {};

    xhr.open("GET", "url", true);
    xhr.timeout = 4000;
    xhr.ontimeout = function () { xhr.abort(); fail(); }
    xhr.send();
```

Or just use `window.setTimeout`

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(),
    timeout;

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
            done(request.responseText);
            clearTimeout(timeout);
        }
    };

    xhr.open("GET", "url", true);
    xhr.timeout = 4000;
    xhr.ontimeout = function () { xhr.abort(); fail(); }
    xhr.send();
    timeout = window.setTimeout(function () { xhr.abort() }, 4000);
```

Comment: is timeout and ontimeout valid for the old xmlhttprequest or the level 2 only ?

Comment: Valid for level 2, and timeout is supported back to IE7. Not sure on level 1.

Comment: this doesn't seem to work with ie8. i guess ie8 doesn't have neither timeout nor ontimeout

Comment: Then instead, you could use `window.setTimeout` to abort the xhr. Just make sure you clear the timeout when `readyState` is 4

Comment: ... or verify `readyState < 4` before doing anything in your timer function.

Comment: @broofa could you elaborate?

Comment: no need to clear the timer if your timer function does `if (xhr.readyState == 4) return;` before anything else (i.e. just let the timer function fire).  not a big deal either way.